# Modify max_run_alarm in Autosys

Tags: autosys

I have a job that copies any file from a directory to an archive directory.  The max_run_alarm is not specified in the job.  The length of time for the job to finish depends on the size of the file.

Since the max_run_alarm is not specified, no notification/email is sent if the job is taking a long time.

Is there a way to add or modify the max_run_alarm when the job is started via sendevent?

Thank you.

We are still in the research phase.

Answer (score 0):

No, the value is evaluated each time the job starts, so you would need to update the max run value before each run.

I would just set it to fixed so in case there is large eventually you will get notified.

If you update the max run during a run, it will not take effect till next run.

Hope that answers your question.